# Emptiness and Om

Tags: personal-practice, philosophy, enlightenment

Somewhere reading the book i found something sensible like 'You think you're right , i think i'm right but at last we're neither right neither wrong.' So what is that which is neither right neither wrong. This might seem little bit confusing. But my interest lies in the question i.e 'What is the emptiness. Whole universe is made from nothing and from everything. Why is our access to the higher intellect restricted? I do know it is the physical limitation and the lack of our proper knowledge of manifestation but why this sort of answer to my own question doesn't even satisfies me.' Why is Om called without end, without beginning, without. This is the thought that striked me after reading one of the Upanishad from Hindu Vedic book i.e Chadogya Upanishada. Please enlighten. Thank you Stack Overflow community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the only truth you will realise is that you just don't know it and you can't.
When they say truth can not be expressed in words because they don't know it. But what happens is that you just accept this and let go off all searching spiritually or wordly.
With realization you just calm down and all your egoic identity loosens.
You got freedom from yourself.

If you want The End of your suffering, you will reach there.

But if it is just  curiosity, then you shouldn't think about these things too much. You may misguide yourself in wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

What is that which is neither empty, neither full, neither right, neither wrong, neither nothing, neither everything, without end, without beginning, without?

Nobody will be ever able to answer such question truthfully nor comprehend it intellectually.

You may think that the answer is too complicated to be comprehended intellectually. Truth is, it is quite the opposite: it's so simple that it can only be comprehended without intellect.

I would say to stop thinking. You're thinking too much. Start meditating. You can find the answer you're searching with meditation.

To point you in the right direction: what is that which is neither right neither wrong? What is that which is nothing and everything? What is that which is without end, without beginning, without? I would say it's Nibanna.

Follow the teachings of the Buddha to attain Nibanna.

Comment: This "answers a question with a question" (in the 1st paragraph); and it advises the OP to "meditate to find your own answer" (in the last paragraph). This might be considered good advice elsewhere (e.g. in person, face-to-face, person-to-person) but isn't considered a suitable form of answer on this SE site.

Comment: Ok. I updated the answer. Maybe it's better.

Comment: I do meditate. Following the principles from the Upanishads. My point is not on the religious aspect that i follow but questions somehow relates to the Spiritual aspect that often triggers me.